# How can I find the Nash-equilibrium of the following zero sum game?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I want to find the Nash-equilibrium of the following zero sum game.  $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&2&-1\\-2&0&3\\1&-3&0\end{bmatrix}$$

I used the Minimax Theorem.

$$min_{x \in X} max_{y \in Y} E(x,y)= min_{(u,x)} \{u; u \ge \sum^{n}_{i=1}a_{ij}x_i, \sum^{n}_{i=1}x_i=1, x_i \ge 0 \} $$

$$max_{y \in Y} min_{x \in X} E(x,y)=max_{(w,y)} \{w; w \le \sum^{m}_{j=1}a_{ij}y_j, \sum^{m}_{j=1}y_j=1, y_j \ge 0 \} $$

$$E(x,y)=x^TAy$$

I can get two linear programs

$$min \, u$$
$$-u-2x_2+x_3 \le 0 $$
$$-u+2x_1-3x_3 \le 0 $$
$$-u-x_1+3x_2 \le 0 $$
$$ x_1+x_2+x_3 =1 $$
$$ x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0 $$

and

$$max \, w $$
$$ w-2y_2+y_3 \le 0 $$
$$w+2y_1-3y_3 \le 0 $$
$$w-y_1+3y_2 \le 0 $$
$$ y_1+y_2+y_3 =1 $$
$$ y_1,y_2,y_3 \ge 0 $$

Then, how can I find the Nash-equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

Let one player's mixed strategy be $(p,q,r)$. Using the indifference condition for mixed NE, the other player's payoffs from each pure strategy must satisfy
$$
\begin{aligned}
-2q+r&=2p-3r\\
2p-3r&=-p+3q\\
1-p&=q+r
\end{aligned}
$$
Line 1 implies 
$$
2r=p+q
$$
Line 2 implies
$$
p=q+r
$$
Together with line 3, we can deduce
$$
p=\frac12,\quad q=\frac16,\quad r=\frac13.
$$
So this is the mixed NE with symmetric strategies.

Comment: There is a unique completely mixed equilibrium (the symmetric one above). There is no other. This is a zero-sum game, so there is either one or infinitely many equilibria and all must have the same value - in this case 0 - and there is no mixed strategy for either player with support size 2 that guarantees a payoff of 0 (which can actually be seen just from the sign structure of the payoffs). You can double check with http://banach.lse.ac.uk

Comment: @RahulSavani: My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: OK, now upvoted.